# External CSS - How do I write/apply tags in HTML page (beginner)

Tags: css, external, apply

My External CSS and template was created by a friend fluent in CSS.  But my friend isn't understanding that I don't know HOW to 'apply' (write) the tags in the HTML page to 'call' the CSS.

I know the difference between id (#whatever) and class (.whatever)   But I don't know if a CSS entry like
        .header caption (with styles listed)  translates then to 
        'p class="header caption" with opening/closing tags  ???

What I'm looking for, but not finding on the web, is a listing of how the most common tags are written as css.  For example, I know
        p class="left"
applies the CSS to align left, instead of HTML tag align="left"    But How do I write the actual tag for 
        .table 
        .td 
        .tr

Is there a website to show:
"This is the tag in HTML, no External CSS"  "This is the way to write the same tag for External CSS"

Second question... Other than for the 'p class' or easy tags, do I start every tag with:
        class=""  ?
        p class="" ?
        div class="" ?

When do I use SPAN vs DIV ?

I have searched for how to apply External CSS, for what tags to use--yes, I understand that every person might use different naming for divs and classes-- but I really need examples that will show the basic tags so I can plug in the 'different naming' from my

'external css'

Is there one website that shows (all on one page) examples of the tags?  A website tutorial that doesn't assume novices already know how to write the tags to apply css?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/ Codeacademy would be a good start for you.

Comment: I don't think what you want exists, mostly because I don't think you quite understand the basics. Start with the basics of HTML and CSS,  n00b's suggestion of w3schools is a good place to start.

Comment: You seem to be asking “how to get started with the basics of HTML and CSS”. This is not a suitable place to ask such questions; the answers would be opinionated (and largely wrong), and what you need depends on your background and situation.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWPMSSsVdPk) is were I got my start in html. It teaches basic html and there are other videos that go along with it.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0afZj1G0BIE) will likely clear up some confusion with css.

Codeacademy.com is a much more thorough course of a multitude of web languages.